# Prometheus: how to sum metric after pod killed?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to apply a simple sum operation to get all accounts created over time.

Last weekend I have deleted and created new pods and my metrics are screwed when I try to run as type "instant". If I change type to range, I can see values but I see a break in my graph:

- Until 2021-06-11: 260k
- 2021-06-14: 7k

In 2021-06-14 should be 267k.

The query is kinda simple:

```
sum(keycloak_admin_event_CREATE)
```

Any idea why it's not summing?

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) into `last_over_time()` function:

```
sum(last_over_time(keycloak_admin_event_CREATE[7d]))
```

The `[7d]` means that the outer sum will take into account the last value for all the time series during the last 7 days.